# BroadcastReceiver doesn't receive when bluetooth is connected

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have added a BroadcastReceiver to my App:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //...
    }
}
```

which should get called, when my phone connects to a bluetooth device.
This is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ginso.myplayer" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:resizeableActivity = "true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service 
            android:name=".NotificationService"/>
        <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.ACL_CONNECTED"/>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But when i connect my bluetooth haedphone to my device, the `onReceive` doesn't get called. I have android 6 and i check all 3 permissions in the `onCreate` of my `MainActivity` and they are all granted(i only had to request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE however). What am i doing wrong?

Comment: the docs say: `android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED`

Comment: thanks, that worked

Comment: of course the same for `ACL_DISCONNECTED`... ;-)